# Spring @Transactional - can one test the number of transactions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have an api class annotated with `@Transactional` as shown.  Some subset of the methods are further annotated with `readOnly=true`.   When writing tests is there any way to verify the number of transactions that actually take place?  Consider if the `delete` method implementation called the `exist` method - then in a test calling `delete` only one transaction should occur.  However, if the test itself calls the `exist` method prior to calling `delete` then 2 transactions should take place.

```
@Transactional
public class AnApi {

    public AnEntity create(EntityData data) {...}

    public void delete(Long id) {...}

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public boolean exists(Long id) {...}
}
```

While I know the framework functions this way, it is preferable to put in tests to detect any future changes and avoid potential surprises.

Comment: You can use Mockito to test the number of times exist() is called, something like Mockito.verify(AnApi, Mockito.times(1)).exists(Any.Long.class)). Is that what you mean?

Comment: While I use Mockito extensively, that won't test the actual number of DB transactions that occur - rather it is telling me the number of times `exist` executed.  If it is called from something like `delete` that already has a transaction open, I want to know it doesn't open another one.

Comment: You could but why? Also it depends on the test if your test is transactional it will still be a single transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That shouldn't be too difficult.

Spring uses a [`PlatfromTransactionManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html) for managing transactions. 
If you register a wrapped transaction manager that implements this interface by delegating to the actual transaction manager, you should be easily able to count the invocations/number of transactions returned.

Comment: I tried many different approaches that led me to get this working - came back here to post about and I ended up doing exactly what this answer says - seemed to be the only way!